# All first worksheets of files created in Excel Online have the same id

Tags: excel, office-js

In my Excel Add-in, developed using the JavaScript API for Office, I need to store some information related to worksheets.

I use the worksheet's `id` using the [Excel.Worksheet.id](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/excel/excel.worksheet?view=office-js#id) property. This works fine in Excel 16 for Mac.

However, when I create a new file in Excel Online, the first worksheet has **always** id `{00000000-0001-0000-0000-000000000000}`. Is this expected behavior or should I file a bug report? Any suggestions on how I can get a unique identifier for any worksheet in all Excel platforms and versions that support the JavaScript API?

(Note that if I create additional worksheets in Excel Online, they correctly get random GUID ids.)

Answer (score 1):

Tiago, I tried this code snippet in Script Lab (http://aka.ms/scriptlab): https://gist.github.com/jakobpn/6bc71cc2be011032ee9e88c2a9732637 in Excel Online. The "Add worksheet" function logs a worksheet id in the console that is different from {00000000-0001-0000-0000-000000000000}.

Maybe you can share a code snippet that can reproduce a new worksheet with an id that is {00000000-0001-0000-0000-000000000000}. If you can reproduce, please file an issue in the office-js repo https://github.com/officedev/office-js/issues.

Comment: I've created a Script Lab snippet and reproduced the problem. I've opened this issue as requested: https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js/issues/552

Comment: Also, I might not have been clear, but the issue is with the worksheet that is already part of a new Excel file ("Sheet1") and not with any other worksheet that is manually added later.